# iterate a sequence of plots

Tags: r

I'd like to be able to iterate through a sequence of plots similar to how `plot.lm()` does

I have this so far but it doesn't update the plot, just shows initial values.

Anyone ideas how to get working as intended?

```
iterateResults <- function(x)
{
    oask <- devAskNewPage(TRUE)
    on.exit(devAskNewPage(oask))
    for (i in 1:length(x))
    {
        plot(x[1]:x[i])
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me; I get a series of ten plots, before each is displayed I need to `Hit <Return> to see next plot:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pause between graphs functionality works for me.  Did you mean to have the key command be `plot(x[seq(i)])` instead?  Otherwise it just plots the indices.

Note that in general `seq(length(x))` is preferred to `1:length(x)` because if length(x)==0 then you've got a problem using the colon operator.  `seq_along(x)` is simpler still.

Comment: `seq_along(x)` would be better

Answer (score 2):

Also, there is the good old `par(ask = TRUE)`